# .htaccess redirect without changing url in users' address bar

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, url-rewriting

My website redirects to `/temp` when visiting the root, I'd like it to appear as the root, without the `/temp` in the URL address bar.

*I have a simple .htaccess:*

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /temp [L]
```

How do I make the address bar show `www.example.com` instead of `www.example.com/temp`?

Also, When I see the network panel, I notice the status code is `301`, so is this equivalent to a `redirect 301`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `RewriteRule ^$ /temp [L]`

If you have a physical directory `temp` in the root of your filesystem... and since you have omitted the slash from the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution then mod_dir will attempt to "fix" the request by appending a slash. It does this by issueing a 301 redirect. (You are then presumably relying on the `DirectoryIndex` to serve the appropriate file from that directory.)

You can resolve this by appending a slash to the end of the substitution, so mod_dir won't try and do this by issuing a redirect. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /temp/ [L]
```

> I notice the status code is 301, so is this equivalent to a redirect 301

Yes, that is a 301 (permanent) redirect.

Comment: That's all of my .htaccess. Unless the host(bluehost) has something on theirs

Comment: I tried it on my own linux server, the behavior is same: http://z.nycweb.io

Comment: I have not paid attention to RewriteRule for a while, so please forgive me. The OP is missing an R. I am not sure if R is assumed. Certainly, a 301 is the default if you do use an R. It seems to me that a R=302 might work better, however, you are the expert. However, if the OP intends to have the entire site run out of the temp directory, they can simply update the Apache .conf file even if it is temporary. Of course this requires a restart. Just my 1.736 centavos.

Comment: @WenShenk Ah... you've probably got a physical directory called "temp"? I've updated (redone) my answer!

Comment: That's right. Good answer, just a `/` was missing. Thanks!